# how to compare bcrypt hash password

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes, bcrypt

I am new to node js, I am trying to validate a password that is encrypted, and I have given the below code which I have tried.

```js
async function passCheck(event) {
  // in event i am passing user entered password and email
  var EnteredPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(event.password, 10); //10 saltrounds

  var fromDB = await pool.query('SELECT password from User WHERE email  = ?', event.emailID);
  if (EnteredPassword == fromDB) {
    //Here i am comparing
    console.log('valid');
  } else {
    console.log('invalid');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bcrypt` has a built-in method for comparing hashes.

```js
async function passCheck(event) {
  var fromDB = await pool.query('SELECT password from User WHERE email  = ? Limit 1', event.emailID);
  // --------------------------------------------------------------------------^
  // Added limit 1 to make sure the only one record will be returned.
  if (fromDB.length > 0 && await bcrypt.compare(event.password, fromDB[0].password)) {
    //Here i am comparing
    console.log('valid');
  } else {
    console.log('invalid');
  }
}
```

DB result sets usually returns an array of objects, therefore, you should check that there are some results (`fromDB.length > 0`) and then pass to the compare method the hashed string itself.

Comment: I think some of the cause for the question is OPs assumption that they can just compare 2 hashes for verification, like with md5. So maybe it has to be pointed out that this compare function can only compare plaintext + hash, but not hash + hash

Comment: "errorMessage": "data and hash arguments required",

Comment: Check what value do you have in fromDB, and pass the password hash as the second argument

Comment: i replaced fromDB[0].password to   fromDB[0][0].password  now it is working thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
  const auth = await bcrypt.compare(EnteredPassword , fromDB)
if(auth ){    
   console.log("valid");
}
else{
   console.log("invalid")
```

}

Comment: no, it's coming as invalid when I enter the correct password.